# I want the status bar to be visible during full screen video playback

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller

I would like to know what code to write in order to show the status bar at the top while a video is being played in full screen mode. I've tried everything that has come to mind but the status bar still becomes hidden when the video starts playing.

Here is the current viewcontroller code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    var player:AVPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let  videoString:String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Buspro", ofType: ".mp4")

        if let url = videoString {
            let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url)

            self.player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)
            self.playerController.player = self.player
        }
    }

    @IBAction func Play(_ sender: Any) {
        self.playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
        self.present(self.playerController, animated: true, completion: {
            self.playerController.player?.play()
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVPlayerViewController  is UIViewController Just subclass and    override `prefersStatusBarHidden`

create New file `CustomAVPlayerViewController.Swift`

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

 class CustomAVPlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController {            
            override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
                    return false
            }
        }
```

**Then At your code:**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var playerController = CustomAVPlayerViewController()
    var player:AVPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let  videoString:String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Buspro", ofType: ".mp4")

        if let url = videoString {
            let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url)

            self.player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)
            self.playerController.player = self.player
        }
    }

    @IBAction func Play(_ sender: Any) {
        self.playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
        self.present(self.playerController, animated: true, completion: {
            self.playerController.player?.play()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry a complete beginner. I dont understand where the first code is supposed to go...  Where would I copy and paste:

class CustomAVPlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController {            
        override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
                return false
        }
    }

Comment: Just create new Swift file called it  `CustomAVPlayerViewController.Swift` or any name you want

Comment: I tried to vote up but it said I dont have enough reputation.

Comment: Can I add you on here? You seem like a helpful person :)

Comment: In my case I was using a WebView which has a youtube video, and I didn't have any access to AVPlayer so I made extension of it and used your method to preserve the bar.